# R. при формировании вектора данных из таблицы в вектор заносит другие числа

Tags: r

Есть таблица которую считываю в R.

```
data <- read.table("lab4_1.csv", sep=";", dec=",", header=TRUE,row.names=1, col.names = c("ПІБ", "Атестат", "Фізика", "Математика", "Укр.М."))
data
dat = c(data[,2],data[,3],data[,4])
dat
```

Вот кусок data:
[image: data]

А вот что заносит в dat:
[image: dat]

[image: datshort]

В самом начале уже видно что числа совсем не те что были в data. 
Информации по R. в интернете маловато,может кто-то подсказать почему заносит именно эти числа и как сделать чтобы заносило нужные столбцы? Не могу понять в чем здесь ошибка.

PS: пробовал делать таблицу с именами(первый столбец не название строк,а отдельный столбец с значениями) и заносить таким же образом только его. Имена менялись на набор чисел,неизвестно откуда взятых.

Comment: а приведите результат выполнения typeof(data) и summary(data). Подозреваю, что числа закачались символами и превратились в факторы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Добавьте `stringsAsFactors =FALSE` в `read.table` , что бы читать текст как текст. Обычно по умолчанию R читает его как factor.

2) Думаю проблема может так же лежать в dec=",", у вас точно запятая разделитель дробной части?

3) Если все что выше не поможет попробуйте сделать `as.numeric(data[,2])` или `as.numeric(as.character(data[,2]))` -- если сработает значит проблема в формате числа и разделителях.

Comment: Да,все таки я не обратил внимания на разделитель дробной части. Хотя и проверял таблицу,но на разделитель и не глянул. 
Исправил на точку и все замечательно заработало.
Спасибо за ответ,надеюсь больше не допущу подобной ошибки. 
Удачи в проф. деятельности ;)

Comment: Добавлю, что так `dat = c(data[,2],data[,3],data[,4])` делать не надо. Можно `unname(unlist(data[, 2:4]))` или `unname(do.call(c, data[, 2:4]))`